# How to get current version of my app on Playstore?

Tags: android, google-apps-marketplace

I want to show an update dialog as the app opens when there is an update of my app on Playstore.

I've tried following code but getting response:

> Appsresponse:-entriesCount: 0

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
                   (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String udid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
MarketSession session = new MarketSession();
session.login("username","password");
session.getContext().setAndroidId("dead000beef");

String query = "pname:<Package name>";
AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder()
            .setQuery(query)
            .setStartIndex(0)
            .setEntriesCount(10)
            .setWithExtendedInfo(true)
            .build();

session.append(appsRequest, new Callback<AppsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ResponseContext context, AppsResponse response) {
               System.out.println("Appsresponse:-"+response);
               // response.getApp(0).getCreator() ...
               // see AppsResponse class definition for more infos
            }
});
session.flush();
```

I might be using the wrong Android ID, but I don't know from where I'll get the Android ID.

Comment: Why is this necessary? The user will know relatively quickly when there is an update, because the Play store will notify the user itself.

Comment: I want user to get notified every time when it opens the app and if the app is not updated

Comment: that is very annoying for the user. please reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

imho as njzk2 says is annoying, but if you want continue on this way you can give a try on this (check on google link example and on github how it's accomplished):

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/Service

https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery

have a nice coding